# Debug jquery in asp. Net app

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a Web app that calls *jQuery* somewhere to show a `<div>`.  Anyone know of a way to intercept that call, see exactly what is calling that `<div>` to appear?

I need to make that div appear on another button and the original button that makes that `<div>` appear has a bunch of stuff that happens and I'd like to isolate only showing of that `<div>`?.

The app is asp. Net Web forms with *jQuery*.

Comment: yes. we know of a way. but to say we'd need to see some code would be putting it mildly.

Comment: @ethorn10, if you do know of a way to break on making particular div visible it may worth to write up answer irrespective of quality of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are generally two ways people do this.

A. They "hide" the div and then "show" it by adding and removing css classes with display:none;

OR

B. They literally remove the div element, and then add it back in.

Either way you can use Chrome developer tools (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview#access) to catch when this happens.

In case A. find the div that's having the CSS class added/removed to it and right click on it. Then click "Break on.." -> "Attribute Modification". That will break the javascript when the node has it's class attribute modified.

In case B. find the parent element where the div is being added/removed. Right click on the parent element "Break on.." -> "Subtree Modification" and this will break when the div is added or removed.

Comment: Thank you all, this is the stuff that I am bad at (jquery and debugging it). I searched the ASP.Net application and found the place where c# injects the jquery code, and in the end, the error was one jquery function was not receiving proper parameter.

I used IE developer tools for debugging, didn't see that option.

and i couldn't put source code because it's spread out over three files (each one seemed important)

Comment: @Rudonja Even if your target webbrowser is IE, I strongly recommend you use Chrome for debugging your front end Javascript/HTML/CSS. It has extremely powerful developer tools and has saved me all sorts of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the source `<html>` you'll notice a `<script>` reference.  This reference will usually either outline the entire *jQuery* code.  The other possible implication will be a reference *URL* to where that `<script>` file is located.

Inside of this file you will see the code for *jQuery* that is allocating that specific `<div>` and *Hiding and Showing*.  Unfortunately without code, it is difficult to specify exact details.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Debugging jQuery Tip**

As @Jazzepi says, Chrome + Developer Tools come in useful when you want to spot problems with your JavaScript code.

Personally, I prefer to use **Firefox** with the **FireBug** extension - you find the JavaScript console and you will see error messages there.

Comment: Just FYI Chrome also has a console as well. You can output to it via console.log() https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#opening_the_console and it does a good job of displaying errors